# What to do with repeated cards

Tags: hearthstone

I'm playing Hearthstone, and looking my card collection I saw that I have repeated more than two cards.

I know that I can only put two of each card in any deck, so my question is:

What do I do with the extra cards?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should disenchant them. You can do this in the *My Collection* screen. This will give you **Arcane Dust**, which is used to [craft new cards](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crafting).

Note that there is a button allowing you to instantly disenchant all the cards you don't need. That button treats golden cards separately, so don't be afraid if you like to keep them.

A small precision about disenchanting (thanks [Kim Minseo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/86613/kim-minseo)) : you shouldn't use disenchanting to exchange one card for another, since it only gives you between 12.5% and 25% of the card's crafting cost, depending on its rarity.

- **Common** (white) cards cost 40 dust (400 for the golden version) and give 5 (50)
- **Rare** (blue) cost 100 (800) and give 20 (100)
- **Epic** (purple) cost 400 (1600) and give 100 (400)
- **Legendary** (orange) cost 1600 (3200) and give 400 (1600)

---

What is also worth noting is that sometimes, a patch may change the behavior of a card ; then, for about two weeks, disenchanting it will give its full value. Hence, you might want to only disenchant when you want to craft a specific card, and when cards are worth their full value.

Comment: Perfect! So I can create different decks with only two same cards?

Comment: Yes ! It doesn't matter if a card is already used in another deck.

Comment: Nice! I was worried about have 2 decks, with the same card, and when disenchant it, loose some card from a deck ^^

Comment: Just note that DE (disenchant) cards give you less than its crafted value - for example a legendary costs 1600 dust, but DE it gives you only 400. But in this case, since you can't include more than 2 of the same cards, then might as well DE the extras.

Comment: Another small gotcha - the auto-disenchant function treats gold cards and standard cards as separate. So even if you've got two cards of a given type, it won't disenchant a gold of that type until you have three of golds of that same type.

Answer (score 8):

You can craft your extra cards into dust, which can then be used to craft into new cards.

Because you can make any number of decks with only 2 of a card (hooray, digital games!) it's a good idea to turn anything you have extras of into dust.

Disenchanting rates are as follows:

Regular (non-gold) cards:

- Common (white) disenchants into 5 dust
- Rare (blue) disenchants into 20 dust
- Epic (purple) disenchants into 100 dust
- Legendary (orange) disenchants into 400 dust

Gold cards:

- Common (white) disenchants into 50 dust
- Rare (blue) disenchants into 100 dust
- Epic (purple) disenchants into 400 dust
- Legendary (orange) disenchants into 1600 dust

When you are in the crafting interface (accessible by the 'crafting' button in My Collection) you can easily turn all your extra cards into dust. If you have extra cards, a button appears in the blank space circled (since I have no extras at the moment, I have no button).

[image: Hearthstone Crafting]

You can find more details (including the cost of crafting cards) on the [Hearthstone wiki crafting page](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crafting).

Answer (score 5):

You can disenchant them for *dust* with the [crafting](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crafting) system. *Dust* is then used to craft other cards that you want.

There is a consideration to make though.

When cards are nerfed, you get more *dust* for disenchanting them for a limited time, so taking that into account, it's suggested that you don't disenchant cards until you have need of the *dust*.